# Android Studio: develop & debug Android app & AppEngine backend

Tags: android, google-app-engine, android-studio

Time has come to migrate to Android Studio from old good Eclipse...

My app has **Android part** and **server part** implemented on **AppEngine**.
The questions that I don't see direct answers to are:

**1)** Should it be 1 Project with 2 modules for Android and server parts, or 2 different Projects?

**2)** How can I debug them at the same time? I'm using REST, so on Eclipse I could in debug mode
         **.a)** watch how http-request on Android's side is formed and just after that
 **.b)** see how it is processed on server's side.
Can I do the same with Android Studio?

Will appreciate your advice & experience very much!
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1) The concept of workspace is a little different so in order to get them both working you should include them in the same AS project as different modules.

2) yes you are fully capable of launching the server in debug mode just like in eclipse.

Comment: Do you know, can I debug android and appengine parts at the same time?

Answer (score 0):

Since AS is dedicated to Android Development, I would not migrate the server part of the app there. I have used the Google App Engine integration on Eclipse, and I am quite content with it. If you have to manage common dependencies between the two projects, this is a different question. Then, maybe, it would be best to not separate them at all.